# can someone explain me this strange behavior in TTexture.assign

Tags: delphi

why when we do ttexture.assign(aTBitmap) then the bitmap data is not copied in the texture if TCanvasStyle.NeedGPUSurface is set. If we do the same with a TBitmapSurface then the data is copied... why such strange behavior ?

```
procedure TTexture.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
var
  M: TBitmapData;
begin
  if Source is TBitmap then
  begin
    if FHandle <> 0 then
      TContextManager.DefaultContextClass.FinalizeTexture(Self);
    FPixelFormat := TBitmap(Source).PixelFormat;
    FStyle := [TTextureStyle.Dynamic];
    FTextureScale := TBitmap(Source).BitmapScale;
    SetSize(TBitmap(Source).Width, TBitmap(Source).Height);
    if not (TCanvasStyle.NeedGPUSurface in TBitmap(Source).CanvasClass.GetCanvasStyle) then
    begin
      if TBitmap(Source).Map(TMapAccess.Read, M) then
      try
        UpdateTexture(M.Data, M.Pitch);
      finally
        TBitmap(Source).Unmap(M);
      end;
    end;
  end else if Source is TBitmapSurface then
  begin
    if FHandle <> 0 then
      TContextManager.DefaultContextClass.FinalizeTexture(Self);
    FStyle := [TTextureStyle.Dynamic];
    SetSize(TBitmapSurface(Source).Width, TBitmapSurface(Source).Height);
    UpdateTexture(TBitmapSurface(Source).Bits, TBitmapSurface(Source).Pitch);
  end else
    inherited ;
end;
```

Comment: noone have a idea ?